# Populating ESRI GeoPortal programmatically?

Tags: mysql, esri-geoportal-server

I'm trying to find either some documentation or an example of how to manually populate the GeoPortal metadata datastore.

I'm using a MySQL backend.  Given a ISO XML file I can manually harvest it but this is tedious and doesn't fit with our model. I can easily write a script to populate entries in the SQL database but it appears that there is more to it than just adding entries to SQL, there is a part that goes into the Lucene engine as well.

Does anyone have any experience or can provide a simple example, how-to or preferably some documentation on populating the datastore?

The goal is to have GeoPortal as an external catalog of locally registered datasets, the trouble is registering the datasets with the GeoPortal catalog in a preemptive manner rather than a reactive (having an administrator manually "harvest" or ingest resources).

Comment: I suggest you look at this topic on the Geoportal Server wiki on [Extending the Web Harvester](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Extending-the-Web-Harvester)